# Remove duplicate keys in dictionary/JSON object from list by keep the highest number

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
te = [
  {
    "Name": "Bala",
    "price": 1
  },
  {
    "Name": "Bala",
    "price": 2
  },
  {
    "Name": "Bala",
    "price": 6
  },
  {
    "Name": "Bala",
    "price": 4
  },
  {
      "Name": "Bala1",
      "price": "None"
  }     ]
```

I would like to remove the duplicates from the "Name" by keeping the maximum from price fields.

I tried:

```
unique = { each['Name'] : each for each in te }.values()
```

The results is on the last name 'Bala' which is price is 4.

```
[{'Name': 'Bala', 'price': 4 }, {'Name': 'Bala1', 'price': 'None' }]
```

What I expect:

```
[{'Name': 'Bala', 'price': 6 }, {'Name': 'Bala1', 'price': 'None' }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add one more to the answers already presented; you can use list comprehension too, using nothing but pure python.

```py
products = [
    {
        "name": "AT-ST",
        "price": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "AT-ST",
        "price": 98
    },
    {
        "name": "AT-ST",
        "price": 100
    },
    {
        "name": "AT-ST",
        "price": 155
    },
    {
        "name": "AT-AT",
        "price": None
    },
    {
        "name": "X-WING",
        "price": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "X-WING",
        "price": 16
    },
]

max_price_products = [
    max(item, key=lambda x: x["price"])  # select the one with maximum price from products with the same name
    for item in (  # iterate in separated products
        filter(lambda x: x["name"] == name, products)  # keep products with different names in different iterables
        for name in set(prod["name"] for prod in products)  # create a set of the names of your products
    )
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a dictionary keyed by the value you want to be unique, then for every element in the list check if new value is higher and update if necessary.

```
res = {}
for elem in te:
    try:
        current = res[elem["Name"]]
        if current["price"] < elem["price"]:
            res[elem["Name"]] = elem
    except KeyError:
        res[elem["Name"]] = elem
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(te)
df_grp = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)['price'].max()
df_grp.to_dict(orient='records')

{'Name': 'Bala', 'price': 6}, {'Name': 'Bala1', 'price': 'None'}
```

Answer (score 0):

same answer but with some handling for none values.

```
unique_d = {}
for d in te:
  if d['Name'] in unique_d:
    if d['price'] != 'None':
      unique_d[d['Name']]['price'] = max(unique_d[d['Name']]['price'],d['price'])
    else:
      unique_d[d['Name']]['price'] = d['price']
  else:
    unique_d[d['Name']] = d
# recast as array ?
unique_a = []
for v in unique_d.values():
  unique_a.append(v)
print(unique_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `max` instead of comparing price by price and `dict.get()` to retrieve a default 0. value for none existing keys.

```
prices = {}

for item in te:
        if item["price"] is not 'None':
            prices[item["Name"]] = max(prices.get(item["Name"],0),float(item["price"]))
        else:
            prices[item["Name"]] = item["price"]



print (prices)
```